# Is the main purpose of Auth0 to hide the implementation of the identity provider from your app?

Tags: authentication, identity, auth0

I’m reading the “Learn the Basics” article on Auth0 [here](https://auth0.com/docs/getting-started/the-basics). It talks about how Auth0 sits between the identity provider (such as Facebook or Google) and the app. The identity provider provides users to Auth0, which in turn provides the same users to the app. The difference is that while the details of the connection between the identity provider and Auth0 depends on the implementation of the identity provider, the details of the connection between Auth0 and the app stay the same, so Auth0 provides users to the app while hiding the details of the implementation of the identity provider from the app. My question is: is this the main point of Auth0? To successfully receive users from the identity provider no matter what the identity provider’s implementation and then forward the users to the app in the same consistent way every time?

Answer (score 0):

Auth0 provides many different features. It can act as the service provider like you describe, or it can act as the identity provider and host the user data. In addition to issuing tokens after authentication, the platform can provide features like role based access control, M2M authorization, and custom hooks and rules based on authentication events. In addition, other features such as multi-factor auth, password reset, email verification, can all be achieved in a turn-key manner using Auth0.